# materialized view logging exclude deletes

Tags: sql, oracle, logging, materialized-views

I am using MVIEWs with Fast refresh to replicate some tables across a network. Everything works great, however I ran into an issue when considering my Delete/Purge process.

The source for the MVIEWs that are feeding the log tables have a data retention of 7 days. Ie I will be running a nightly purge process to delete data older than 7 days from current date.
The target MVIEWs however are on an ODS and have a data retention policy of 30 days. Also, these MVIEWs are NOT currently populating another schema or set of tables.

Problem is, when I Delete from the source tables, those delete statements will propagate through to the target MVIEWs and now I no longer have 30 days worth of data - only 7.

Is there a way to exclude logging DELETE for the MVIEW log tables? I noticed in the MLOG$_Table_Name there is a column 'DMLTYPE$$'. Could I somehow delete from the Log table all records where DMLTYPE$$ = 'D'?

Thanks everyone, and yes, I did try researching this online first.
Regards,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you could manually delete data from the materialized view logs before running the refresh.  That would probably work.  But it would not be a solution that I'd be really comfortable with.  It would be a very bespoke solution that would probably not be officially supported.  And it if there might ever be another materialized view that depends on the materialized view log, you'd have to ensure that you're only deleting those rows that relate to your materialized view's subscription.  Plus, the materialized view on the destination would need to be updatable in order for you to be able to manually remove the rows older than 30 days via a separate process.

If these are the business requirements, something like Oracle Streams (or GoldenGate) would be a much more appropriate architectural solution.  Those products are designed to give you more flexibility about which logical change records (LCRs) you apply.  In Streams, for example, it is easy enough to create a custom apply handler that discards delete LCRs.  And since you're applying LCRs to a table on the destination rather than a materialized view, your 30 day purge process is much easier to manage.  This would be a relatively common Streams setup rather than a very unique materialized view setup.

Comment: We were looking at using Streams as an option, but the dev and implement time was so short for MVIEWs it seemed the best way to go. But you make a good point. And GoldeGate isn't an option wither due to cost. Perhaps best option is to align the retention policies to both 30 days. It's not a huge amount of data and the difference is manageable. thanks very much Justin.